# select_tag and rendering form for selected value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I have working form_for @company. But in controller: @company = Company.first. I have many companies and I want to choose company by select_tag and when I select company in view page this form_for work with this company. Ho can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a select_tag before your form like this:

```
= select_tag :chosen_company_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, 'id', 'name')
```

Then with javascript (jquery variant) do:

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
  $('#chosen_company_id').change(function(event){
    url = "http://your.domain.com/companies/" + $(this).val();
    document.location.href = url;
  });
});
```

And don't forget to change your controller code to:

```
@company = (params[:id] ? Company.find(params[:id]) : Company.first)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. But it didn't work, because this javascript render all the page with $(this).val(). I want to re-render only form_for in this page withaut chanche url... How can I make it?

Comment: You can refactor the form out into a separate action and then, instead of changing the document location, you might use a jquery ajax call to this action, sending it the id of the chosen form. Have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/ for specific instructions.

Comment: mm, good, but how can achieve this without the use of jquery, ajax? how can make it with only rails functionality?

Comment: You can not. You will at least need javascript (jquery or prototype just simplify the task).